# Parse XML document in Ruby

Tags: xml, ruby

I'm using REXML library.

```
<foo>
  <baa>value</baa>
</foo>
```

I want to get the value that belongs to `<baa>`.

How can I do it?

Comment: I assume your XML is supposed to be "<foo><baa>value</baa></foo>", i.e. with ending tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
require 'rexml/document'

doc = REXML::Document.new File.new('mydoc.xml')

doc.elements('*/foo/baa') { |element| puts element.get_text }
```

I prefer Nokogiri and Hpricot gems myself. You can try them if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'rexml/document'

xml = <<-EOS
<foo>
  <baa>value</baa>
</foo>
EOS

doc = REXML::Document.new(xml)
doc.root.elements.each("baa") { |element| p element.text }
```

If you want to collect values you can use to_a.map or inject instead.
See [REXML::ELements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/classes/REXML/Elements.html#M002908).

Answer (score 0):

Rishav's solution throws for me.

```
11:50:18 Temp$ ruby rx.rb
rx.rb:5:in `elements': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
        from rx.rb:5
11:50:25 Temp$
```

Here are some alternative approaches:

```
require 'rexml/document'

doc = REXML::Document.new DATA

doc.elements.each('//foo/baa') { |element| puts element.get_text }
baas = REXML::XPath.each(doc, '//foo/baa/text()') {|txt| p txt}
p baas

__END__
<foo>
  <baa>value</baa>
</foo>
```